# Adding a controller with read/write actions and views using entity framework results in a warning

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Hi I am following the steps from this tutorial :

> http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application

When I try to add a controller that use one of my models , I get this warning:

[image]

This is the model based on witch I am tryng to create the controller:

```
public class Student
{
    public int StudentID { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string FirstMidName { get; set; }
    public DateTime EnrollmentDate { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Enrollment> Enrollments { get; set; }
}
```

And this are the setting that I am adding when I try to create it :

[image]

I am not really sure what that warning is telling so I do not know If I posted the correct information needed in order to solve it.If anything else is needed I will post it later.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: build project once, and try out

Comment: I did it I still get the same warning.What did work was changing the provider from System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0 to System.Data.SqlClient

Comment: try adding your prev comment as an answer and mark it as accepted. In order to help future searches on SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason changing the provider from System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0 to System.Data.SqlClient seems to solve this problem.